# Gooey css effects with contrast parent

Tags: css, css-filters

I'm trying to create gooey effect with CSS only **(without svg)**.
Everything goes right but my parent container has a `contrast filter` and I can't use colors on my child elements (the contrast filter changes the colors).

Does someone know of a **basic** way to make this effect with only CSS or reverse the contrast filter to get my right colors on the child elements?

**My code:**

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

.blobs {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  filter:contrast(20);
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20);
}

.blob {
  background:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 2.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px black;
}

.blobs:hover .blob:first-child {
  transform:translateX(-70px);
}

.blobs:hover .blob:last-child {
  transform:translateX(70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

**When I'm coloring the child elements:**

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

.blobs {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  filter:contrast(20);
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20);
}

.blob {
  background: rgb(255, 113, 93);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 2.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px rgb(255, 113, 93);
}

.blobs:hover .blob:first-child {
  transform:translateX(-70px);
}

.blobs:hover .blob:last-child {
  transform:translateX(70px);
}

.original-color {
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(255, 113, 93);
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
<div class="original-color"></div>
```

[My fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/2u3fo5u6/)

Comment: If it can helps you: http://codepen.io/mirajm212/pen/Iivdj

Comment: Hi @RedBreast, unfortunately its not. in your example the color changes because the contrast filter on the parent. I'm looking for a solution for this behavior and make the children element with the correct color. change your red to green and you see the problem

Comment: Sorry I'm no help, but this is really cool :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have taken your effect. On the container, I have set a pseudo element that covers it, with whatever color you want.

And with a mix-blend-mode, I can set this color where the container is black, keeping the remaining white:

(By the way, a very nice effect !)

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

.blobs {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  filter:contrast(20);
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20);
}

.blobs:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: coral;  
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.blob {
  background:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 1.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px black;
}

.blobs:hover .blob:first-child {
  transform:translateX(-70px);
}

.blobs:hover .blob:last-child {
  transform:translateX(70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

Added another way to get your request. This is harder to set up, but will work on Edge, where filter is available but blend modes do not.

This snippet involves using 2 of your previous setting, and a different primary color for each. (You could already achieve primary colors with your original setting).

To get a particular color, you set different alphas to the 2 settings, and somehow you can achieve any color that you want (even though the process is not easy)

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

.blobs {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  filter:contrast(20);
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20);
  opacity: 0.99;
}


.blob {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 2.5s;
}

.blobs:hover .blob:first-child,  
.blobs:hover ~ .blobs .blob:first-child {
  transform:translateX(-70px);
}
.blobs:hover .blob:last-child, 
.blobs:hover ~ .blobs .blob:last-child {
  transform:translateX(70px);
}
.blobs:nth-child(1)  {
  opacity: 0.57;
}
.blobs:nth-child(1) .blob {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px red;
}
.blobs:nth-child(2)  {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.08;
}
.blobs:nth-child(2) .blob {
  background: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px yellow;
}
.test {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 113, 93);
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Another try, this time with a more complex filter.

The color is achieved with a hue-rotate

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.blobs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(-25deg);
  filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(-25deg);
}
.blob {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 1.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px red;
}
.blobs:hover .blob:first-child {
  transform: translateX(-70px);
}
.blobs:hover .blob:last-child {
  transform: translateX(70px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
```

Another try, this time a single div ....

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, red 100px, transparent 140px), radial-gradient(circle, red 100px, transparent 140px);
  background-position: -150px 0px, 150px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(35deg);
  filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(35deg);
  transition: background-position 2s;
  animation: crazy 13s infinite steps(12);
}
.test:hover {
  background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
}
@keyframes crazy {
  from {
    filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    filter: contrast(20) hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Trying to get a solution that works cross-browser . 
Added javascript to check blend-mode availiabily.

Just click the button to run the function.

```js
function check () {
  if('CSS' in window && 'supports' in window.CSS) {
    var support = window.CSS.supports('mix-blend-mode','lighten');
    if ( ! support) {
      var element = document.getElementById('blobs');
      element.classList.add('compat');
    }
}
}
```

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

.blobs {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #fff;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  filter:contrast(20);
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20);
}

.blobs:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background-color: coral;  
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.blob {
  background:black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  border-radius:100%;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.82, 0.1, 0.24, 0.99) 1.5s;
}

.blobs:hover .blob:first-child {
  transform:translateX(-70px);
}

.blobs:hover .blob:last-child {
  transform:translateX(70px);
}

/* compatibility */

.blobs.compat {
  -webkit-filter:contrast(20)  hue-rotate(-25deg);
  filter:contrast(20)   hue-rotate(-25deg);
}
.blobs.compat:after {
  content: none;
}

.compat .blob {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs" id="blobs">
  <div class="blob"></div>
  <div class="blob"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: really nice! i think this property don't support on IE, you have a IE solution? thank you!

Comment: Thank you @vals but its don't works like your first snippet. i need a full support solution and i don't know what to do. :(

Comment: hi @vals, the color looks different from than your defined and have a strange shadow on hover. :(

Comment: The way to get the final color is a little complicated, as I pointed out in the answer. Since you can only use primary colors and the complementaries, you need to adjust the final color playing with the alpha of the 2 elements. I have edited the answer to get a color more or less equal to the one in your question. But I don't see a shadow. I have slowed down the transition, but I still can't see the shadow ...

Comment: thank you for your time. take a look in this image: https://i.imgsafe.org/b49f404766.png

Comment: Safari and chrome on macbook

Comment: I can not test on Mac .. but I have made a change, just trying to guess what could be the issue.  It was already working ok for me on PC, chrome and FF

Comment: I have had another idea ... Let's see what happens in a Mac

Comment: Stil dont work in safari...its jump and change color on hover.

Comment: Every browser render perfect result but safari dont... :/

Comment: I am running out of ideas ....  Wasn't the first snippet working on safari ? (but not on IE) May be you can go with the blend idea, with any one of the others snippets as a fallback (just for IE) ?

Comment: Its a very good idea!! How can i handle the property by browser type?

Comment: Added snippet that does this. The function that checks the availability is run on a button click, just call it on the load or similar

Comment: Thank you @val, for everything!

Comment: Happy that it helped ! ... It has been hard :-)

Answer (score 3):

For this answer, I only had to make a change to the filter property

```
contrast(15) contrast(.5) sepia(1) brightness(1.85) hue-rotate(319deg) saturate(3.45)
```

- First, we set the contrast to 15 (20 made the edges a little too hard, if you ask me)
- Then we set it back to .5 (Yes, you can stack these things)

So now we have a lightgray background and darkgray blobs

- Apply sepia (which gives it a color)
- Add 1.85 brightness (now the background is white again, and we have colored blobs)
- hue-rotate to get to the right hue
- saturate to give it its saturation

The last three properties in the list are essential for getting the right color. Your goal is rgb(255, 113, 93). With this line applied, the colors are rgb(255, 115, 94)

You can see it work in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/qbgjok60/)

As a sidenote. You can also stack transforms, which means that if you want to center the blobs, you won't have to use negative margins, but use the `translate(-50%, -50%)` trick. Then when you hover over them, you can simply stack the transforms like this `translate(-50%, -50%) translateX(-70px)`

Comment: on hover its change the color to black. :(

Comment: I believe there is some kind of bug around this in safari  ...  Your fiddle works ok on PC