# How to apply the complex SVG filter to the HTML element that includes the animated child elements in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, svg-filters

I have a parent element and his childs (div in div). When I apply the SVG filter to the parent element all works as expected, the filter applied to the whole parent element and his child. But if I add the animation to the child element the filter stop working and child element stay unchanged.

In Chrome all works fine and the elements flow into each other. But in Safari elements pass through each other without necessary visual effect.

[Example](http://codepen.io/EddiG/pen/WRybgv?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<div class="rect-wrap">
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  padding: 100px;
}

.rect-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.rect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  animation: rect 5s infinite;
}

.rect:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2500ms;
}

@keyframes rect {
  from, to {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
}
```

Please advise how can I apply this complex SVG filter to the HTML element with animated child elements?

**Workarounds**

***HTML to SVG***
Convert HTML elements into the SVG elements and apply the animation to this new elements.
[Example](http://codepen.io/EddiG/pen/LxrNLq)

***JS animation (poor performance in iOS Safari)***
Use the JavaScript animation instead CSS.
[Example](http://codepen.io/EddiG/pen/BpVNgR)

Comment: may be this answer is of interest (the effect seems similar) http://stackoverflow.com/a/40409314/1926369

Comment: thank you @vals, very useful